# Getting specified output using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two table where data is like below --
 These are sample tables

```
create table test_1 (Designation varchar2(500));
create table test_2 (Competencies varchar2(500));

insert into  test_1 values  ('Asst Manager - Accounts'  );         
insert into test_1 values ('Automation Lead'          );         
insert into test_1 values ('BSA Trainee'              );         
insert into test_1 values ('Business Analyst'         );         
insert into test_1 values ('Development Manager'      );         
insert into test_1 values ('Facility Supervisor'      );         
insert into test_1 values ('Head - Engineering'       );         
insert into test_1 values ('Head - Solutions Delivery');         
insert into test_1 values ('HR Executive' );                       
insert into test_1 values ('IT Consultant');
insert into test_1 values ('LAN support administrator');
insert into test_1 values ('Senior Manager, QA');
insert into test_1 values ('Manager, Technical Support');
insert into test_1 values ('Manager-HR');
insert into test_1 values ('Principal Architect');
insert into test_1 values ('Project Coordinator');
insert into test_1 values ('Project Lead');
insert into test_1 values ('Project Manager');
insert into test_1 values ('QA Consultant');
insert into test_1 values ('QA Engineer');
insert into test_1 values ('QA Lead');
insert into test_1 values ('QA Trainee');
insert into test_1 values ('Recruitment Executive');
insert into test_1 values ('Senior Development Manager');
insert into test_1 values ('Senior Manager - Administration / Procurement');
insert into test_1 values ('Senior Manager - Finance');
insert into test_1 values ('Senior Manager, QA');
insert into test_1 values ('Senior QA Engineer');
insert into test_1 values ('Senior Software Designer');
insert into test_1 values ('Senior Software Engineer');
insert into test_1 values ('Senior Technical Account Engineer');
insert into test_1 values ('Senior Technical Writer');
insert into test_1 values ('Software Engineer');
insert into test_1 values ('Software Trainee');
insert into test_1 values ('Solution Designer');
insert into test_1 values ('System Administrator');
insert into test_1 values ('Tech Lead');
insert into test_1 values ('Technical Account Engineer');
insert into test_1 values ('Technical Training Specialist');


insert into test_2 values  ( 'Adherence to processes');
insert into test_2 values  (  'Adherence to schedule and timelines');
insert into test_2 values  (    'Analytical Thinking');
insert into test_2 values  (   'Communication Skills');
insert into test_2 values  (     'Consistency');
insert into test_2 values  (   'Discipline (Epicor/ office timings/   responsiveness etc)');
insert into test_2 values  ( 'Initiative/ ownership/ acheivement    orientation');
insert into test_2 values  (  'Organizational activities (interviews/ trainings/ internal blogs etc)');
insert into test_2 values  ('Quality of deliverables');
insert into test_2 values  ('Self Development (what initiatives have you taken)');
insert into test_2 values  ('Team , peer, stakeholder relationships');
insert into test_2 values  ('Time Management');


select t1.Designation, t2.Competencies from test_1 t1, test_2 t2;
```

Now the output of this should be like

```
Desgnation                          Competencies
software engineer                list of all the competencies
Automation Lead                 list of all the competencies
```

and so on for all the designations like for all desgnations we need all competencies in another column.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the competency string is not too long, then you can use `listagg()`.  I would recommend:

```
select t1.Designation,
       (select listagg(t2.Competencies, ', ') within group (order by Competencies)
        from test_2
       ) as competencies
from test_1 t1;
```